# IBM Db2: How to automatically activate databases after (re)boot?

Tags: cron, db2, systemd, db2-luw

I have several Db2 databases that I want to automatically [activate](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002038.html) after a system reboot. Restarting the Db2 service after a reboot is not a problem, but activating the databases requires access to the instance profile.

Service start/stop is crontrolled by system / systemctl. Including some user-controlled setup scripts into those scripts doesn't seem like a good idea. I briefly looked into [enable-linger](https://helpmanual.io/help/loginctl/) for the Db2 instance user or to use [EnvironmentFile](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd#EnvironmentFiles_and_support_for_.2Fetc.2Fsysconfig_files) to set up the instance profile.

How do you activate all or a set of databases after reboot? Do you use user/group/EnvironmentFile with systemd? Do you enable linger or do you have any other method?

Comment: If the server is highly-available (HACMP, or similar clustering (but not HADR) ), there are usually  jobs to start on the active-node, so I  use scripting for activation of databases triggered by the cluster startup sequence.   For systemd, one could either define a new service (with relevant dependencies) , or extend the existing service-file to run a script to activate local databases.

Comment: @mao for extending the service-file, do you have experience with handling the env setup?

Comment: not sure what you mean. I did change the suggested db2fmcd.service for my requirements on a couple of physical linux, as the IBM suggested one does not handle anything except the simplest case.

Comment: and did you adapt it to activate a database? if yes, would you share how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple script which must be run from the Db2 instance owner.
It assumes, that Db2 instance is auto started. If it's not the case, just comment out `db2gcf -s` and uncomment `db2gcf -u`.
The script waits for the instance startup a configured number of seconds, and activates all local databases found in the Db2 instance system directory.
The script may be scheduled to run at the OS startup via Db2 instance owner's crontab entry as shown.
Log file (see the ${LOG} variable) with commands history is created in the Db2 instance owner's home directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Function: Activates all local DB2 databases
# Crontab entry:
# @reboot /home/scripts/db2activate.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
#

TIMEOUT=300
VERBOSE=${1:-"noverbose"}
export LC_ALL=C
if [ ! -x ~/sqllib/db2profile ]; then
  echo "Must be run by a DB2 instance onwer" >&2
  exit 1
fi
[ -z ${DB2INSTANCE} ] && . ~/sqllib/db2profile
if [ "${VERBOSE}" != "verbose" ]; then
  LOG=~/.$(basename $0).log
  exec 1>>${LOG}
  exec 2>>${LOG}
fi
set -x

printf "\n*** %s ***\n" $(date +"%F-%H.%M.%S")
# Wait for the instance startup 
# (or even start it with 'db2gcf -u' instead of checking status: 'db2gcf -s')
TIME1=${SECONDS}
while [ $((SECONDS-TIME1)) -le ${TIMEOUT} ]; do
  db2gcf -s
  # db2gcf -u
  rc=$?
  [ ${rc} -eq 0 ] && break
  sleep 5
done

if [ ${rc} -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Instance startup timeout of ${TIMEOUT} sec reached" >&2
  exit 2
fi

for dbname in $(db2 list db directory | awk -v RS='' '/= Indirect/' | grep '^ Database alias' | sort -u | cut -d'=' -f2); do
  db2 activate db ${dbname}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple script which must be run from the Db2 instance owner.

su - `<INSTANCE>`

db2iauto -on `<INSTANCE>`

## Exiting

exit

## run user root

./`<INSTANCE>`/sqllib/bin/db2fmcu -d;

cd /`<INSTANCE>`/sqllib/bin/

./db2fmcu -u -p /opt/ibm/db2/`<VERSION DB2>`/bin/db2fmcd

./db2fm -i `<INSTANCE>` -U

./db2fm -i `<INSTANCE>` -u

./db2fm -i `<INSTANCE>` -f on

ps -ef | grep db2fm|grep `<INSTANCE>`

## Done